# How are return statements executed in C if there are multiple return statements?

Tags: c, return

According to my knowledge of C, in the following code the first return statement in the function `fact` should be executed. Instead, the last return statement in function is executed. How does the code work here? Why is the first return statement in the function `fact` not executing?

Factorial of a number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 2, count = 1, fact0 = 1;

int fact(int n) {
    if (n == count) {
        return fact0;//Only this return statement should be executed
    }
    fact0 = fact0 * a;

    a++;
    count++;
    fact(n);
    return 1;//But this return statement is executed , Why?
}

int main() {
    int n;
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    printf("Enter the factorial number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("The factorial of the number is %d", fact(n));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Enter the factorial number
 4
The factorial of the number is 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Lastly, please don't use line-numbers in the code you show, it makes it very hard for us to copy the code to try for ourselves.

Comment: sure i'll remove the line numbers and i'll read every guide you have sent .

Comment: As for your problem I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Both some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) as well as stepping through the code line by line in a debugger should show you the problem quite quickly.

Comment: Why should that return statement be executed when you input `4` and `count` is `1`?

Comment: If you enter `4` and `count` is `1`, then 4 isn't equal to 1, not even for large values of 4. As a result the first return statement is not executed. QED.

Comment: (Off topic: you do *not* get "banned" for a single downvoted question. Even with a number of badly received questions, you don't get a "ban". You get a *timeout* in which you cannot ask new questions. That is to prevent people asking bad questions, over and over again. Downvoting indicates that your question is thought to be unclear and/or not well researched -- and you can prevent that.

Comment: The first return is in a conditional block, it is executed only if the condition `n == count` is true.  The function is recursive - it calls itself.  It is poor implementation - if called a second time, it will not work correctly because it relies on static data.  Often both the practice of multiple returns and recursion is discouraged.  This poor example is an argument for avoiding the latter.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `count` value gets incremented

Comment: @Clifford Yeah it's a bad implementation but I want to know how the code works ?

Comment: @Allan : Step the code in a debugger to see what is going on - it will return from the second return until `count` is incremented to `n` - note it calls itself,   You call it once, but it is called `n` times in total - returning to itself until `count == n`.  It is still horribly broken - if you "found" this code, do not regard it as a good example of coding.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you expect it to return from the first return, but you do not explain why you have that expectation - because to us it seems obvious.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for your suggesstions but I really don't know how to debug a code because i'm new to programming . Anyway thanks for helping out.I know it's a bad code because it was written by me , lol.

Comment: Knowing how bad code works is perhaps a pointless exercise (because it does not work!).  The issue of how recursion works can be demonstrated with code that is not also broken - the broken implementation is just a distraction you don't need.

Comment: @Allan : using a symbolic debugger should be the second thing you learn right after "hello, world".  Despite its name, a "debugger" is also a valuable learning and testing tool.  You could have learned the fundamentals of using a debugger in the time you have spent writing and commenting on this question already, and there are a great many more questions you will never need to ask once you master the debugger.  Try it out at https://www.onlinegdb.com/ if you don't know how to run your local debugger.

Comment: @Clifford As per my understanding , the first return statement should be executed .The second return statement shouldn't be executed because there is a function call before the last return statement .This means that the second return statement should never be executed . Am i correct? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @Clifford I'll surely learn to debug.Thanks for spending your time in this code.

Comment: @Clifford I have understood finally . Thank you very much.

Comment: @Allan : No you are not correct.  But any clarification to your question should be added by editing the question rather then adding a comment which few will read.  Before the recursive call, count is incremented, the recursive call will return and the second return statement will be called.  The first return will be called exactly once (at least the first time it is called from `main()`), after which the recursion unwinds.  In recursion, you must have one "inner-most" return that does not recurse further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bunch of nested function calls. The innermost returns from where you expect, the others from the other `return` statement.

```
// 1st call, in main
fact(4); // calls fact(4) with count == 2
    fact(4); // calls fact(4) with count == 3
        fact(4); // calls fact(4) with count == 4
        return fact0; // as expected
    return 1;
return 1;
```

Comment: then why the output is printing 1 instead of fact0?

Comment: Because it prints the value returned from the function it called: the very first one ... which returned `1`. The function that returned `fact0` was not called by `main()`.

Comment: @Allan :  Because the code is broken - but that is not what you asked about.  Swap the return statements to correct it.  At least partially correct it - it is still broken in other ways.

Comment: @pmg @Clifford So the `main()` only obtains the `return` statement of the function which it called first . You saved my life guys .Thanks `@pmg` and `@clifford` .

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn how to debug your code. A good start is to modify `fact` like this:

```
int fact(int n) {
    printf("a: %d count: %d fact0: %d n: %d\n", a, count, fact0, n);
    if (n == count) {
        printf("n is equal to count\n");
        return fact0;//Only this return statement should be executed                                               
    }
    fact0 = fact0 * a;

    a++;
    count++;
    fact(n);
    return 1;//But this return statement is executed , Why?                                                        
}
```

Then, a run would look like this:

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter the factorial number
4
a: 2 count: 1 fact0: 1 n: 4
a: 3 count: 2 fact0: 2 n: 4
a: 4 count: 3 fact0: 6 n: 4
a: 5 count: 4 fact0: 24 n: 4
n is equal to count
The factorial of the number is 1
```

That should give a pretty good clue of what's going on. Insert more print statements if needed.

Comment: @Allan As I said in the beginning of the post. You need to learn how to debug your code. That's the best advice I can give you. Introduce more printouts if needed and try to execute the code with pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with a value like 4 you enter some levels of recursion.

As soon as all sub-calls finish the program just goes ahead and executes the last return statement, which gives you 1 in any case.

A working approach would be to return fact(n) instead of just calling it and removing the last return statement instead.